# Jackson mapping a relationship

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'm using Jersey and am expecitng a POST as an entity.  However thst POST will also contain the `UUID` for one of its relationships:

Jersey Resource:

```
@POST
public WorkstationEntity save (WorkstationEntity workstationEntity) {
            //WorkflowProcessEntity workflowProcessEntity = workflowProcessService.findByUUID();

    workstationService.save(workstationEntity);
    return workstationEntity;
}
```

How can I adjust the following mapping so it'll recognize the relationship and save correctly?  Currently the `workflow_process_id` is NULL when it's saved and I have to query for the entity manually.

The JSON being posted is... `{name: Workstation 1; workflow_process_id: 1}`

```
private WorkflowProcessEntity workflowProcess;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_process_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public WorkflowProcessEntity getWorkflowProcess() {
    return workflowProcess;
}

public void setWorkflowProcess(WorkflowProcessEntity workflowProcess) {
    this.workflowProcess = workflowProcess;
}
```

**workstationService**

```
@Transactional
public void save(WorkstationEntity workstationEntity) {
    workstationRepository.save(workstationEntity);
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `workstationService`? are you using Hibernet or or simple jdbc or any other orm tool

Comment: I am pretty sure I can help help you as I have used jpa, jersey and jackson extensively but I do not understand your question. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw - When json is mapped to an object, is it possible to have a "user:{id:4}" map as a JPA User Entity instead of a user object with a populated ID column?

Comment: Yes but you would have to use the entity manage merge operation to reattach the entity to the entity manager. AFAIK this is the recommended way to get from a POJO to managed entity. You can probably automate this by using a jackson mixin for your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show code for `workstationService`? are you using `Hibernatr` or simple `jdbc` or any other `orm tool`?

I think inside `workstationService.save(workstationEntity);` you will need to attach `workstationEntity` to session (in case of Hibernate Hibernate Session). and then `save` it..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem it is that the returning json has a null id for the attached WorkstationProcessEntity id field. This is most likely a problem when you are trying to persist / merge the entity the transaction is not being committed before returning the detached entity. If you are using a persist make sure that you commit the transaction otherwise the id's will be null. Otherwise if you are using a merge this will commonly fix the problem.

```
protected T persist(T obj) {
    EntityManager em = ThreadLocalPersistenceManager.getEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        if (! tx.isActive()) {
            tx.begin();
        }

        em.persist(obj);
    } finally {
        if (!tx.getRollbackOnly()) {
            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The other likely cause is that your fetch is not set to eager so the datastore will only fetch the entity when it is accessed and by the time you are returning from the post the child entity is not attached. This is the most likely cause for your problem. What you should try is to access the workstation entitites getWorkflowProcess before closing the entity manager. Otherwise the attached entities will be null. Or add the FetchType.Eager annotation to fetch the child entities from the database when the parent is accessed.

Comment: What I would recommend over adding the fetchtype.eager is to use a servlet filter for your REST operations, this will make sure that the children that are accessed are attached.